# How to achieve dynamic Language download and change in android [Using AAB]

Tags: android, localization, android-app-bundle, google-play-core

In my android application I am looking to support In-app localisation.
The following things I want my app to support.

1. Download the new languages strings (strings.xml) from server as and
   when they are updated with new strings or new strings added.
2. Use power of android Resource system to use new strings Ex.
   R.string.some_title (after the download)
3. Switch to new language without restarting the complete app.

Now, the 3rd one I am able to achieve.

Issue is with the first 2.

I am relatively new in Android development.

Came across Android App Bundle and ability to download new languages.

So my assumption is, once the app is uploaded (with default languages strings), If new languages are added I will submit new AAB with new languages or with new strings are added in same language strings xml. Am I correct here ?

I will install new languages when needed using

```
SplitInstallRequest
```

Please suggest few pointers to achieve this via AAB.